# How much does a Black Box Underwater Locator Beacon (ULB) cost?

Tags: flight-data-recorder, cost

I'm curious if anybody can provide a **rough price estimate for a commercial aviation ULB like those used on Black Boxes**.

Area of interest: Europe i.e. Euros, EASA CS-25.

<sup>(For instance the RJI ULB-362 or the Dukane DK-120, but any equivalent is good)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

There is one listed here on [Ebay for $750](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/201468749609?lpid=82&chn=ps&ul_noapp=true). Some of the makers like [L-3 list contact info](http://l-3ar.com/tso-c121b/SIL_L-3AR-2015-0005_90-Day_Beacon_retrofit_kits_rev-.pdf) for getting pricing, all of the other sales sites I am finding look like you need to submit for a price quote.